# Refactor by removing if and else conditions

Tags: java, refactoring

Below snippet in my method uses lot of if and else condtitions. I would like to avoid it using some way. How can I achieve the below functionality by having a config using HashMap for each type?

```
        boolean success = true;
        if (source.isTypeA()) {
            if (!model.getPermission || !source.hasAccess) {
                success = false;
            }
        } else if (source.isTypeB()) {
            if (source.condition() && (!model.getPermission() || !source.hasAccess)) {
                success = false;
            }
        } else if (source.isTypeC() && (!source.isMobile || !model.getPermission)) {
            success = false;
        } else if ((source.isTypeD() && source.condition) && (!source.isMobile || !model.getPermission)) {
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
```

Comment: Well you could remove quite a lot of nesting by just returning as soon as you know what you'll return...

Comment: You have a long list of conditions which, if true, mean `success` is false. Therefore something in the form of `boolean success = !(a || b || c || ...)` will do what you want without branching.

Comment: I want a solution where I can avoid using if and else. Say using an HashMap having a config for each type. But I am unable to come up with that.

Comment: Is the source your own class? Can you add public methods to it?

Comment: @David Yes its my own class. I can add public methods to it

Comment: `if(source.isTypeA()) { return (!model.getPermission || !source.hasAccess()); } else if (source.isTypeB()) return source.condition() && (!model.getPermission() || !source.hasAccess()); } //... etc`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use some more polymorphic solution.
Make source to be an interface, with an isSuccess method.
TypeA, TypeB, TypeC and TypeD are implementations of that interface, all implementing its own version of isSuccess. Then you won't need that whole if statement at all.

```
return source.isSuccess(model);

class TypeA {
    public boolean isSuccess(Model model) {
        return model.getPermission() && hasAccess();
    }
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Types are non-overlapping, a switch statement combined with Jon Skeet's suggestion of mid-function returns gives you this:

```
switch (source.getType()) {
    case TYPE_A:
        return model.getPermission() && source.hasAccess;
    case TYPE_B:
        return !source.condition() || (model.getPermission() && source.hasAccess);
    case TYPE_C:
        return model.getPermission() && source.isMobile;
    case TYPE_D:
        return !source.condition() || (model.getPermission() && source.isMobile);
    default:
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Way:

```
private boolean codeUsingALotOfIfElse(Source source, Model model) {
    if (source.isTypeA() && (!model.getPermission || !source.hasAccess)) return false;
    if (source.isTypeB() && (source.condition() && (!model.getPermission() || !source.hasAccess))) return false;
    if (source.isTypeC() && (!source.isMobile || !model.getPermission)) return false;
    if ((source.isTypeD() && source.condition) && (!source.isMobile || !model.getPermission)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

---

Second Way:

```
private boolean codeUsingALotOfIfElse(Source source, Model model) {
    int caseInt = getIntMappingFromSourceType(source); //This function returns a value that can be used for switching.
    switch(caseInt) {
    case *intA*: 
        return (model.getPermission && source.hasAccess));
    case *intB*:
        return !(source.condition() && (!model.getPermission() || !source.hasAccess));
    case *intC*:
        return source.isMobile && model.getPermission;
    case *intD*:
        return !(source.condition && (!source.isMobile || !model.getPermission));
    default:
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall use strategy design pattern to create different strategy class based on your `source` type, and to determine the `success` based on different criteria of different strategy class. By such way are you be able to conforming to open/closed principle.

A code sample is as below. You could take a look at a [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Science_Design_Patterns/Strategy) of strategy pattern.

```
interface SuccessInterface{
    boolean IsSuccess(Object model);
}

interface SuccessFactoryInterface{
    SuccessInterface Create(Object source) throws Exception;
}

class SuccessTypeFactory implements SuccessFactoryInterface{

    @Override
    public SuccessInterface Create(Object source) throws Exception {
        switch (source.getType()) {
            case typeA:
                return new TypeA();
            case typeB:
                return new TypeB();
            case typeC:
                return new TypeC();
            case typeD:
                return new TypeD();
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}

class TypeA implements SuccessInterface {
    private Object _source;

    public TypeA(Object source) {
        _source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean IsSuccess(Object model) {
        return model.getPermission() && _source.hasAccess();
    }
}

class TypeB implements SuccessInterface {
    private Object _source;

    public TypeB(Object source) {
        _source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean IsSuccess(Object model) {
//        add your criteria here
        return false;
    }
}

class TypeC implements SuccessInterface {...}

class TypeD implements SuccessInterface {...}
```